# WCF CommunicationException When Subscribed Clients Abort Abnormally

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe

In a WCF publish/subscribe setup, I currently have an Unsubscribe() method in place to gracefully disconnect clients from the WCF host when the client is closed or needs to stop listening; however, this does not handle cases in which the client aborts forcefully or abnormally, such as the computer itself losing power. If a client application dies in such a way, then its channel remains and the following error is received at the publisher the next time it tries to send out messages:

```
ExceptionDetail> was caught
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
```

Clients subscribe anonymously, and the publisher follows a multicasting structure (any subscribed clients/channels should receive the message). Although I am able to catch the exception, I do not know how to single out the faulty channel from this point in the code in order to dispose of it and allow other clients to continue receiving messages. My publishing code looks similar to the following:

```
public static void Publish(DateTime sendTimeStamp, DataTable sendTable)
        {
            InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(null, new PublishStatus());
            MessagesClient publishingClient = new MessagesClient(context);
            try {
                publishingClient.PublishMessage(sendTimeStamp, sendTable);

                if (publishingClient.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    publishingClient.Close();
                else
                    publishingClient.Abort();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {
                // This is where the error is caught  
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {

                publishingClient.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                publishingClient.Abort();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to isolate the faulty channel from this point (at which the exception first picks up on the issue) and dispose of it so that the publishing service itself can continue to send messages?

Comment: I can't really get it, as I see you are talking about server, but the code you provided very looks like client's code. Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: The code was from a publisher (Windows service) that periodically sends messages out to clients, who subscribe and listen for them. You are right in that a lot of this exception code would usually be on the client's side as well though if it were going to pass messages back. Managed to find a solution, but thank you for your time. =)

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error as well as exception research, an additional try-catch block in my WCF host was able to unsubscribe incorrectly aborted clients and keep the error from coming back to the publishing service. Posting a simple version here in case someone else stumbles on the same type of problem:

```
public static event MessageEventHandler MessageEvent;
        public delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, ServiceEventArgs e);

        IClientContract callback = null;
        MessageEventHandler messageHandler = null;

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientContract>();
            messageHandler = new MessageEventHandler(Publish_NewMessageEvent);
            MessageEvent += messageHandler;
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            MessageEvent -= messageHandler;
        }

        public void PublishMessage(DateTime timeStamp, DataTable table)
        {
            ServiceEventArgs se = new ServiceEventArgs();
            se.timeStamp = timeStamp;
            se.table = table;
            MessageEvent(this, se);
        }

        public void Publish_NewMessageEvent(object sender, ServiceEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // This callback was causing the error, as the client would no longer exist but the channel would still be open and trying to receive the message
                callback.ReceiveMessage(e.timeStamp, e.table);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Unsubscribe the dead client.
                Unsubscribe();
            }
        }
```